# Clip-path gradient animation not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, clip-path

I have an animated gradient logo. It's made with an inline svg path that I've used as a clip-path to a div with an animated gradient background. Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. I tried having the `clip-path` attribute both with and without the `-webkit-` prefix, and none works. With the prefix, nothing displays. Without the prefix, the gradient animation shows as it is without the clip-path.

Thanks to anyone who can help out!

I've put the code in codepen: https://codepen.io/lanlanonearth/pen/JgYPYa

Comment: What version of Safari? Seems to work fine for me on 12.1.1

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting on my first post. I just found the answer and got it to work so you saw the fixed version! It seems that Safari has some bug mapping the coordinate system between svg and html elements. Simply adding `transform: translateZ(0)` as sort of a reset to the div took care of it. This link explains it: https://github.com/emilbjorklund/svg-weirdness/issues/27

Comment: you can answer you own question detailing the solution you found, it will be helpful for everyone

Comment: I was planning to but I read somewhere that I'm not eligible to post my own answer since I am very new to stack overflow so I thought I couldn't. I do see a "Post Your Answer" button on this page. I will try to see if it will let me post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed after stumbling upon this link explaining it: [CSS clip-path only works properly on first element in Safari 10 #27](https://github.com/emilbjorklund/svg-weirdness/issues/27) It turns out that Safari has some bug mapping the coordinate system between svg and html elements. Simply adding `transform: translateZ(0)` as sort of a reset to the div took care of it.